# Javascript: Duplicate each string value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Tried googling for a while but couldn't find my answer. I am trying to take a 3-character string and convert it to a 6-character string in which each of the 3 characters is duplicated.

For example, `3ff` would become `33ffff`.

First, I'm turning the string `3ff` into the array `["3", "f", "f"]`.

After I converted to an array, I tried to map through the array and `*2` each value, hoping to get the new array `["33", "ff", "ff"]`.

However, I am getting the new array `[6, NaN, NaN]`.

I understand that 3 is getting multiplied by 2 for 6, and that JS doesn't know how to multiply strings so we get NaN.

I thought that in Python, if you try to `*2` a string value, it will just duplicate the value, like `eggs` will turn into `eggseggs`. Is this not the case in JS?

Here is my code:

```
const duplicate = function(v) {
  newArray = v.split("");
  doubledArray = newArray.map(i => i*2);
  return doubledArray
};

console.log(duplicate("3ff")) // Output: [6, NaN, NaN]
```

Is there a way to duplicate string values of an array in JavaScript, and not just number values?

Comment: No it's not possible to multiply. But you can just do `i => i + i` instead

Comment: @Alto JavaScript, where `'1'+'1' == '11'`. Python, like Ruby, has string-specific overrides for `*`. JavaScript does not.

Comment: `"3ff".split('').map(x => x.repeat(2)).join('')`

Comment: Thanks @Alto! Tried this and it works great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `.repeat()` function like:

```js
const duplicate = (v) => v.split("").map(i => i.repeat(2));
console.log(duplicate("3ff"));
```

Old notation:

```js
const duplicate = function(v) {
    newArray = v.split("");
    doubledArray = newArray.map(i => i.repeat(2));
    return doubledArray
};
console.log(duplicate("3ff"));
```

Comment: I hadn't heard of the repeat function before. Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use arrays for this:

```js
console.log('abc'.replace(/./g, '$&$&'))
```

In regexp language, a dot means "any symbol" and `$&` = "the found symbol"

Comment: Oh cool! I didn't even think that there could be a way to do this without using arrays. This is a good tip I'll keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you

```js
const duplicate = function(v) {
  return [...v].map( i => i.toString() + i).join('');
};

console.log(duplicate("3ff"))
```

Comment: Ahh, I see what you did there. Thanks for this suggestion! So many creative ways of doing the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const duplicate = function(v) {
    newArray = v.split("");
    doubledArray = newArray.map(i => i + i);
    return doubledArray.join("")
  };

console.log(duplicate("3ff"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow like this.

```
doubledArray = newArray.map(i => i+''+i);
```

Because I may be a number, so you should add string.

Comment: string + string is always another string

Comment: But if the `i` is numeric value, it will be calculated.

Comment: Ah I see. I was looking at "3ff"

Comment: `i` is not a number. split('') creates array of strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatination using [string template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const duplicate = function (v) {
  return [...v].map((c) => `${c}${c}`);
};

console.log(duplicate("3ff"));
```

Comment: Makes sense! I would never have thought of this. So useful to see everyone's different thought processes of going through the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answered! There were many ways to do this, but here were the two simplest for me to understand:

1.) Use `repeat`, like this:

```
const duplicate = function(v) {
    newArray = v.split("");
    doubledArray = newArray.map(i => i.repeat(2));
    return doubledArray.join("")
};

console.log(duplicate("3ff")); // Output: 33ffff
```

2.) Use `i + i`, like this:

```
const duplicate = function(v) {
    newArray = v.split("");
    doubledArray = newArray.map(i => i + i);
    return doubledArray.join("")
  };

console.log(duplicate("3ff")); // Output: 33ffff
```

Thanks all for the great suggestions!